# Send data from a fragment to another fragment with nested viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

how to send data from a fragment that is part of a viewpager, to another fragment that is also in a viewpager. The problem is when in fragment 1 by a spinner select a data, this data has to go to fragment B.

[image]

Comment: To avoid all trouble, just store your data in `shared preference`. You can use with Gson to convert whole list to string and retrieve data with 1 key

Comment: Lo solucione utilizando RXBus2

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using RxBus2. Use the Warrenth library. I leave the link to your repoitorio https://github.com/warrenth/RxBus2